# Connect my JWT to .NET Core's IHttpContextAccessor.User

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a JWT that is sent in a header with they key "**X-JWT-Assertion**".

It arrives just fine.  I can validate successfully it using a `IAuthorizationFilter`.

I then inject a `IHttpContextAccessor` into my controller and check the `User` property (a `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity`).  It has no claims in it despite my JWT having many claims.

My guess is that my WSO2 server is sending the JWT in a non-standard header name so the .NET Core code does not know it is there.

I could just manually access the JWT to get my claims out, but I would rather use the built in .NET methods.

**Is there someway I can connect my JWT with the `IHttpContextAccessor.User` object?**

Comment: Please post your `Startup.cs` code that configures your application's Authentication and Authorization. Using `IAuthorizationFilter` will not automatically map JWT claims to `ClaimsPrincipal` claims. Also, ASP.NET Core has built-in JWT claim mappings that usually need to be cleared because they're useless and counterproductive: https://leastprivilege.com/2016/08/21/why-does-my-authorize-attribute-not-work/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you don't need to inject `IHttpContextAccessor` to your controller for accessing the user. `Controller` already has a `User` property.

Second, You need to add jwt authentication in your `startup.cs` and then change the way it reads the token from with events.

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(configureOptions =>
    {
        configureOptions.Events.OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            context.Token = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-JWT-Assertion"];
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    });
```

Comment: I am going to accept this answer.  I created another one that outlines my further issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58599759/connect-a-jwt-to-the-user-property-in-a-controller

Comment: How can I access the User from controller. What is the syntax please?