# Connect a JWT to the User property in the Controller

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a Web API .NET Core 3.0 Service.  It gets a header that contains a JWT with claims.

I added the following to `ConfigureServices` in Startup.cs to map my JWT to the .NET Core Authentication system:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(configureOptions =>
{
    configureOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
    {
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            context.Token = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-JWT-Assertion"];
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});
```

I also added `app.UseAuthentication();` to `Configure` in Startup.cs.

I then fire up my service and call an HTTP GET operation on it.  When I do, I can see that the `context.Token` is set to my JWT.  If I take that JWT over to https://JWT.io it shows that it has many claims.

**But a break point in the GET operation shows that `User.Claims` is empty.**  What ever is needed to connect the JWT to the User is not happening.

Here are variations that I have tried:

- Add `[Authorize]` above my controller:
  *Result:* 401 Error: Unauthorized
- Add `[Authorize(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` above my controller
  *Result:* The AuthorizationPolicy named: 'Bearer' was not found.
- Add `services.AddAuthorization()` in ConfigureServices and `[Authorize]` above my controller
  *Result:* 401 Error: Unauthorized
- Add `[Authorize(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` above my controller and code below to ConfigureServices :

```
    services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
    {
        auth.AddPolicy(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
            new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
    });
```

*Result:* 401 Error: Unauthorized

To be clear, I don't want to do any Authorization, but I read that adding it may be needed to map the claims to the user.

**What do I need to do to get the User property (that is part of the Controller base class) to be populated with my claims?**

Comment: Please show your full `Configure` method code please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there is something wrong in your configuration. In the `ConfigureServices` method it should be as follows:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
   options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
   options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
       ValidateIssuer = true,
       ValidateAudience = true,
       ValidateLifetime = true,
       ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
       ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
       ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
       IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
    };
});
```

Then in the `Configure` method it should be as follows:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...................

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization(); // These two must be before `UseEndpoints` and after `UseRouting`

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```